# combine Like (String Pattern) with Case in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to combine `Like` with `Case` in a VBA code. My current code is able to remove all sheets whose name does not match the names in range A:

```
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
Dim wbook As Workbook, xWs As Worksheet
Dim DeleteSheetFlag As Boolean

Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("A2")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wbook = ActiveWorkbook

For Each xWs In wbook.Worksheets
    DeleteSheetFlag = True

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Select Case xWs.Name

            Case MyCell.Value, "Summary"
                DeleteSheetFlag = False
                Exit For

        End Select

    Next MyCell

    If DeleteSheetFlag Then
        xWs.Delete
    End If

Next xWs

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I want to change it in that way, that it removes all sheets whose name are not **similar** to the names in Range A. If I would be able to get something like

```
 Case **Like** MyCell.Value, "Summary"
                DeleteSheetFlag = False
```

the problem would be solved.
I mean with similar the pattern match which we know from [Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te33kb6t.aspx). In my case I have for example two sheets with the names : **Etat1** and **Etat1(2)** and I want to put in [image: Range A11] the string **Eta** in order to keep both.

Comment: What do you mean by 'similar'? Can you give us some examples?

Comment: @nekomatic: I added the example into the question

Answer (score 3):

To force this you would need to use a workaround like this:

```
Select Case True
     Case MyCell.Value Like "*Summary*"
           Debug.Print "!"
           'DeleteSheetFlag = False
           '...
     Case MyCell.Value Like "*OtherCase*"
           DeleteSheetFlag = False
           '...
End Select
```

Comment: I cannot understand this statement **Case MyCell.Value Like "*OtherCase*" ** because I want to say if xWs.Name finds a pattern in MyCell.Value. It dose not work

Comment: Great and correct answer. However, an `If` structure might be more appropriate for this purpose.